# How can I update arrayList inside document?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I want to update `recipIds` array list inside users document the array list gets wiped and new value is set.

I tried to get the old collection then add new value to it and update but that just seemed overkill.

```
public void saveRecipeIds(User user) {
    String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    userMap.put("recipeIds", user.getRecipesIds());

    db.collection("users").document(currentUserId).update(userMap);
}
```

I want to update my array list with new value without wiping old list data.

Here is how it looks in Firestore:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXGyf.jpg

Edited:

```
public void saveRecipeIds(User user) {
    String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    userMap.put("recipeIds", user.getRecipesIds());

    db.collection("users").document(currentUserId)
        .update("recipeIds", FieldValue.arrayUnion(userMap));
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZeOF.jpg

Edited

```
public void saveRecipeIds(User user) {
    String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

//  Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
//  userMap.put("recipeIds", user.getRecipesIds());

    db.collection("users").document(currentUserId)
        .update("recipeIds", FieldValue.arrayUnion(user.getRecipesIds()));
}
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.UserData$ParseContext.createError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:293)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:261)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.convertAndParseFieldData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:202)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseArrayTransformElements(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:440)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseSentinelFieldValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:346)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:248)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.convertAndParseFieldData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:202)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseUpdateData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:176)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.update(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:213)
        at com.example.cookingapp.Repository.UserRepository.saveRecipeIds(UserRepository.java:143)
        at com.example.cookingapp.ViewModels.UserViewModel.saveRecipeIds(UserViewModel.java:57)
        at com.example.cookingapp.Views.Fragments.Home.FinishRecipeFragment$1.onClick(FinishRecipeFragment.java:111)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11090)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the `recipeIds` array, you should use `FieldValue.arrayUnion` like in the following line of code:

```
db.collection("users").document(currentUserId)
    .update("recipeIds", FieldValue.arrayUnion("newRecipeId"));
```

**Edit:**

In order to be able update an array, for instance by adding a new element, you need to pass to the `arrayUnion()` method a String (the id itself). You **cannot** pass a list or an array of strings. There is no way you can do that. You can add/remove an element from an array, one by one.

If you want to update the array with another array, you should first get the document from the database, make the necessary changes client side and then write it back into the database.

Comment: Hi Justinas! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hello, yes I tried but now it returns me  array inside of other array. how to prevent it ?

Comment: Are you using the same code I have provided you? Please add the exact code that you are using to your question.

Comment: That's the normal behaviour since you are passing as the first argument a map. To solve that pass a literal String and not a map, `.see arrayUnion("newRecipeId")` ? In your case would be `.arrayUnion(user.getRecipesIds())`

Comment: I now get this error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported

Comment: Please show the code that produces this error. Add it to your question.

Comment: Edited. Should I replace this edit with previuos one ?

Comment: Sorry about that, my mistake. You shouln't pass `user.getRecipesIds()`, because this is an array, you should pass the id itself. With other words, pass a only a String. Does it work now?

Comment: Can you please explain it better because I cant understand how i pass String when I take a list of ids.